# Squeel syntax for field = value OR field IS NULL in a loop

Tags: ruby, activerecord, squeel

I'm trying to recreate the following syntax using squeel by using a loop:

```
WHERE season = "value" OR season IS NULL
```

I was able to get this far:

```
where do
  ((season == entry["season"]) | (season == nil)) &
  ((episode == entry["episode"]) | (episode == nil)) &
  ((imdb == entry["imdb"]) | (imdb == nil)) &
  (YEAR(theatrical) == year)
```

However, the problem is I want to do it **in a loop** so I don't have to do conditionals for when the values are empty (for example if imdb doesn't have a value I wouldn't even use that line).

I have this:

```
entry = { "imdb"=>"0364725", "media"=>"DVD", "season"=>"1", ...}
entry.each do |k,v|
    ((k == v) | (k == nil))
  end
end
```

But it does not put the `field IS NULL` bit in the SQL.

If it's not possible with Squeel, might it be done with ActiveRecord?

Ultimately, I'm looking for a way to avoid having conditionals for those fields in the SQL. As I said above, if the field is empty I don't list them at all, but if it has a value I need to do the whole `field = value OR field IS NULL` bit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The whole code I'm trying to use at the moment is this:

```
matches_found = 
includes(:dvd_director, :dvd_upc, :dvd_series).limit(1).
where do
  (title == title_to_search) &
  entry.each { |k,v| ((k == v) | (k == nil)) }
end
```

Note that everything after the `|` is getting ignored whether I use `__send__(k)` or not.

**More info:**
One very strange thing is that if I use anything other than the `k,v` it gets ignored. For example:

```
    entry.each { |k,v| ((k == "bob") | (k == v)) }
```

"Bob" gets ignored! and the value (v) gets put into the SQL without the `OR` statement.

Comment: Did you miss some lines in the code? It seems your question boils down to: "how to use attribute names from variables with squeel?": `table.send(var)`

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking, see the edits in the original question to see that one of the options in the `OR` statement is getting ignored and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only solution I could come up with was to add `nil` into the array itself for Squeel to process it properly:

```
entry.each do |k,v| 
   # we add a nill value so Squeel will do the OR field IS NULL
   entry[k] = [v, nil] if k == "upc" || k == "asin" || k == "freebase" || k == "imdb" 
end
```

This is ugly but it works. Now I'm sure there is a nicer way to write all those `or's` in the 3rd line but that's another question :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need `__send__`:

```
where do
  (title == title_to_search) & entries.map do |k, v| 
    (__send__(k) == v) | (__send__(k) == nil)
    # or: __send__(k) >> [v, nil]
  end.inject(:&)
end
```

https://github.com/ernie/squeel/wiki/Tips-and-tricks

Comment: Can I remove the table command and still use `.send`? I'll try it. Simply because I have joins in there that would complicate things if I have to specify the table. The joins are taken care of with a `.includes`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. With or without the `__send__` it is ignoring everything after the `|`. If I list them explicitly (as in the example in the original question), it works, but once I put it in a loop, the OR part gets ignored.

Comment: are you trying it with the map+inject? it's weird, that works for me here.

Comment: No, no map. Let me post the whole code I'm using in the original question.

Comment: a `each` generates no expression, try `map` + `inject` like I show in the answer.

Comment: Copy/pasting your code gives me this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION doghouse_data.inject does not exist: SELECT (joins...) WHERE ((`dvdpedia`.`title` = 'Underdog' AND inject(`map`.`&`))) LIMIT 1`